# CakePHP - Calling another model causing "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation"

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm new to cakePHP and i have looked everywhere for an answer, but couldn't find the reason for this.
I'm trying to call a function in distant model, if i run the model directly, it works fine, but if i run it from another model, it cause 'Syntax error or access violation' error.

Here's the code:

**Cpanel Controller**

```
class CpanelController extends AppController {

    var $uses = array('Client');

    public function index() {
        $this->Client->index();
    }

}
```

**Client Model**

```
class Client extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'users';
}
```

**Client Controller**

```
class ClientController extends AppController {
    public function index() {
        echo "running";
    }
}
```

When i run it from mysite/Client , it runs just fine.
But if i try to load it from mysite/Cpanel , it throws:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'index' at line 1
```

Thank you,

Comment: what is the code inside `Client` model `index` action.?

Comment: Just a simple echo as shown in the example, i want to test if before running any actual code

Comment: i am seeing that you have `echo "running";` inside `Client` controller.....share entire code.

Comment: This is the entire code, for now

Answer (score 1):

You dont' have a `index` function in your `User` Model.

maybe you what you intended to do was

```
public function index() {
        $this->Client->find('all');
    }
```

otherwise you have to create a index function inside the model

```
class Client extends AppModel {

    public $useTable = 'users';

    public function index() {
       // Do Something;
    }
}
```

If you want to use UserController inside CpanelController here's the code

```
App::uses('UserController', 'Controller');
$UserController= ClassRegistry::init('UserController');
$UserController->index();
```

Comment: Thank you, but i want to write the code inside the Client Controller. Let's say i have a function run_code() inside Client controller, how can i run it from the Model? I tried $this->run_code() and $this->Client->run_code() .

thanks for helping

Comment: @DanielaVolt you can do it by calling controller into model and then use it. **Example**  `App::import('controller','ControllerName');`

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Is it the correct use of cakePHP? i read here in stackoverflow that using import isn't recommended, also calling controller directly from other control is not a best practice. This is why i tried to Client controller from Client modal. So, is it a bad practice to call controller directly from a controller?

Comment: @DanielaVolt Why do you want to call a controller from another controller? If there is functionality you want to share between controllers, you might want to have a look at components.

Comment: I agree with @dhofstet, maybe think about of creating your own component. In my opinion it's not a good practice to call a controller inside another controller because it breaks the MVC pattern